# What do the red x's on the physical map represent?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Folks who buy a physical copy get a physical map to go with it:

[image: Skyrim map]

What do these x's mark? Standing stones? Shrines?

Comment: X marks the spot.

Comment: Just to clarify, pre-order was not required. I went with a buddy to Walmart last night and bought the PC version, and it came with the 'premium physical map', which is a nice card stock map. But it was just the regular PC version, on the shelf. No pre-order.

Comment: Where was that X mark?

Comment: @Jim There's one right under the "So" in "Solitude" in the NW corner. Click on the picture for a higher resolution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems they are generally points of interest related to Nord mythology. I methodically went to each X on the map, and here's what I found:

#### Guardian/standing stones

1. Northeast of Markarth: The lover stone
2. Northwest of Solitude: The steed stone
3. East of Morthal: The lord stone
4. Northwest of Morthal: The apprentice stone
5. West of Winterhold: The tower stone
6. East of Whiterun: The ritual stone
7. Eastmarch: The Atronach stone
8. South southeast of Riften: The shadow stone
9. Lake Ilinalta: The lady stone
10. (11.) (12.) Near Riverwood: The mage, warrior, and thief stones

The Serpent stone isn't marked on the map because, according to Nordic culture, the Serpent is the symbol of evil and is waging a constant war against the three guardians, those being the Thief, Mage, and Warrior stones, and those guardians' charges, those being the Lover, Steed, Lord, Apprentice, Tower, Ritual, Atronach, Shadow, and Lady stones.

#### Other points of interest

- Southwest of Rorikstead: Valthume
- North of Markarth: Ragnvald
- West of Karthwasten: Shrine to Peryite
- West northwest of Dragon Bridge: Volskygge
- West southwest of Solitude: The Statue of Meridia
- Southeast of Morfal: Labyrinthian
- Southwest of Winterhold: Alftand
- Southwest of Dawnstar: Mzinchaleft (I think: can't find anything else around here)
- West of Dawnstar: High Gate ruins
- South of Lake Jorgrim: Irkngthand
- The Velnontht Mountains (Northern): Mzulft (I think)
- The Velnontht Mountains (Southern): Kargrenzel
- South southwest of Riften: Forelhost
- West of Lake Honrich: Avanchnzel

Comment: there could be both standing stones and other features. And, anyway, if there are 13 standing stones and 3 are in the same place, that would be ELEVEN x's. You don't subtract 3; you subtract the two extraneous ones.

Comment: @MathWizard Yep, you're correct; I'm starting to go through them systematically and finding a mixture of guardian stones and other points of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Those would be the standing stones. They seem to match up closely with their locations especially the one by Riverwood. It also says so on this site: 
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Guardian_Stones

Answer (score -4):

They are dragon burial sites. It's not anything complicated or magical.

Comment: Does it look like those are burial sites?