# Besides perks, what other permanent abilities can I get?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In [another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35576/how-many-total-perks-are-there-in-skyrim/35579#35579), it was mentioned there were other permanent abilities besides perks.

What are they, and where can they be found?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a number of different permanent abilities besides the normal perks that you can get:

#### Guardian stones

There are the 13 guardian stones, found at [locations throughout the world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35114/what-do-the-red-xs-on-the-physical-map-represent/35195#35195):

- **Warrior:** Combat skills increase 20% faster
- **Thief:** Stealth skills increase 20% faster
- **Mage:** Magic skills improve 20% faster
- **Lover:** All skills improve 15% faster
- **Apprentice:** 2x magicka regeneration, twice as vulnerable to magic
- **Atronach:** +50 magicka, 50% magic absorb, -50% magicka regeneration
- **Lady:** +25% health and stamina regeneration
- **Lord:** +50 damage resist, 25% magic resist
- **Ritual:** All dead things around you become undead and fight for you
- **Serpent:** Attacks have a chance to paralyze targets for 5 seconds and 25 damage
- **Shadow:** 60 second invisibility power
- **Steed:** +100 weight capacity, no movement penalty from armor
- **Tower:** You can unlock one expert-level or lower locked door/chest per day without lockpicks

These are mutually exclusive: you can only have one active at any time. If you have the [Aetherial Crown](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Aetherial_Crown), you can activate 2 Standing Stones.

#### Quest-related "perks"

There are a few permanent abilities you get as a result of completing various side quests:

- **Ancient Knowledge** (+25% Armor if wearing all Dwarven armor, smithing skill increases 15% faster) received for completing *Unfathomable Depths*
- **Sailor’s Repose** (10% more health from healing spells) for completing *What Lies Beneath*
- **Sinderion’s Serendipity** (25% chance of creating an extra potion during alchemy) for completing *A Return to Your Roots* in Blackreach

#### Guild "perks"

These are received while completing quests for each of the "guilds" or organizations in the world:

- **Assassin's Aegis** (+25% Armor if wearing all Dark Brotherhood Armor) for completing the Dark Brotherhood quest, *Sanctuary*
- **Dragon Infusion** (25% less melee damage from Dragons) for completing the Blades quest, *Dragon Research*
- **Prowler’s Profit** (chance of finding additional gems in chests) for completing the Thieves' Guild quest, *No Stone Unturned*
- **Nightingale’s Aegis** (+25% armor if wearing all Nightingale set pieces) for completing  the Thieves' Guild quest, *Trinity Restored*

#### Permanent blessings of the Divine

While all the Divines have temporary blessings you can get for visiting their shrines, Dibella and Mara have quests that allow you to get a permanent blessing from them:

- **Agent of Mara** (+15% Resist Magic) received for completing *The Book of Love*
- **Agent of Dibella** (+10% melee damage to the opposite sex) received for completing *The Heart of Dibella*

#### Meditations

After completing the initial Greybeards quests that are part of the main storyline, you can speak to Paarthurnax who will give you one of three meditations:

- **The Fire Within:** the Fire Breath shout does 25% more damage
- **Force Without Effort:** You stagger 25% less while enemies stagger 25% more
- **Eternal Spirit:** +25% health regeneration while ethereal

You can only have one meditation active at any given time, but you can switch at any time by speaking to Paarthurnax again.

#### Nightingale Agent status

You can select one of three gifts after completing "[Darkness Returns](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Darkness_Returns)":

- **Shadowcloak of Nocturnal:** For 120 seconds you automatically become invisible while sneaking.
- **Nightingale Subterfuge:** People and creatures in the spell's area of effect will attack anyone nearby for 30 seconds.
- **Nightingale Strife:** Instantly absorbs 100 points of Health from the target.

These are permanent, activated powers that can only be used once per day. Similarly, you can swap between the three gifts by revisiting the Twilight Sepulcher, but only once per day.

#### Unimplemented abilities

These abilities are mentioned in the official strategy guide, but do not appear to be implemented in the game (yet?):

- **Archmage's Authority** (Better prices from members of the College) for completing  the final College of Winterhold quest, *The Eye of Magnus*
- **Gift of the Gab** (speech skill increases 15% faster) for completing the Bards College quest, *Tending the Flames*

Comment: I don't understand *Tower*.  What does it mean by "One free expert-level or lower unlock"?

Comment: @TM. You can unlock a an expert-level locked item without lockpicks once per day.

Comment: Are we presuming there are at least 6 more "Divine Blessings" that you've yet to discover, or are those the only two?

Comment: @RavenDreamer There are other blessings you can get for going to shrines, but the Agent blessings are the only ones that are permanent.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Right, I meant, are there 6 more Agent blessings?

Comment: @RavenDreamer All the Divines have temporary blessings; only Mara and Dibella have permanent Agent blessings.

Comment: Do vampirism and lycanthropy count as permanant abilities?

Comment: @Arkive I wouldn't consider them permanent abilities: vampirism is a disease, and the benefits of lycanthropy come from transforming, which only lasts a few minutes.

Comment: @"Agent of Dibella" Is there a reference for it being melee only damage? Says "combat damage" in game which makes me think it would at least cover ranged if not magic.

Comment: You missed the "Agent of" abilities from completing the Thieve's Guild quest ["Darkness Returns"](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Darkness_Returns).

Comment: Also, the "Blessing of" abilities are not mutually exclusive. I got Dibella and have had Mara for a while and both show up on my "Active Effects" list.

Comment: @agf Thanks, added the confirmation about the Agent blessings. As far as I understand from that page the "Darkness Returns" abilities are active short-duration powers, not passive/permanent abilities like what's documented here.

Comment: @MarkTrapp they work the same as Tower/Shadow/Ritual Guardian Stones. If those three are on the list, so should ones from Darkness Returns.

Comment: Gift of the Gab is bugged, at least on the PS3 version, you don't get the perk for completing 'Tending the Flames'. @Raven Dreamer Would be cool if there is 6 more "Divine blessings" but I doubt it, since it probably would have been mentioned in the official strat guide. Perhaps they will add more in DLC? Personally I hope their DLC quests are longer then the ones for each faction you join. I mean like 3 quests to become an Archmage? lol

Comment: Any idea what exactly needs to be done to get the "Assassin's Aegis" ability? I don't seem to get any bonus from wearing all DB armor and I don't see it on my "Active Effects" list. I have completed the DB quest chain.

Comment: You should add the [nightingale agent bonuses](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Nightingale_(Skyrim)) to your list

Comment: You guys win: Nightingale Agent added.

Comment: Gift of the Gab does not actually exist in the game at all, there are no reports of anyone getting it, even with console commands. archmages authority and dragon infusion both are bugged and need to be added with console commands. So they are unobtainable on PS3 and XBOX.