# What do blessings do in Skyrim, and where can I find them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just got "Blessing of Talos", but I don't know what it really gives me. where can I find that information in the game? I would like to know what this blessing does as well as others that I might encounter.

What do blessings do in Skyrim, and where can I find them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Besides perks, what other permanent abilities can I get?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36433/besides-perks-what-other-permanent-abilities-can-i-get)

Comment: Not a duplicate, as blessings are not permanent, and these blessings are not covered in that topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in your menu->magic->active. Hover over each item, and you will see in the description of the effect what gave you that, and it will say 'blessing of talos'.

Comment: It'd be great if you could write up a summary of each one here for people who are too lazy to get them all in the game

Comment: @DavidFullerton See Rafaels answer. He beat me to the copy/paste. ;)

Answer (score 17):

> **Blessing of Akatosh** *Magicka regenerates 10% faster.*  Regenerate Magicka, 10 pts for 28800 secs
>
> **Blessing of Arkay** *Increases your health by 25 points.*  Fortify Health, 25 pts for 28800 secs
>
> **Blessing of Dibella** *+10 Speechcraft.* Fortify Persuasion, 10 pts for 28800 secs
>
> **Blessing of Julianos** *Increases your Magicka by 25 points.* Fortify Magicka, 25 pts for 28800 secs
>
> **Blessing of Kynareth** *Increases your stamina by 25 points.* Fortify Stamina, 25 pts for 28800 secs
>
> **Blessing of Mara** *Healing spells restore 10% more.* Fortify Restoration, 10 pts for 28800 secs
>
> **Blessing of Nocturnal** *You are 10% harder to detect.* Fortify Sneak, 10 pts for 28800 secs
>
> **Blessing of Stendarr**       Block 10% more damage with your shield. 
>   Fortify Blocking, 10 pts for 28800 secs
>
> **Blessing of Talos** *Time between shouts is reduced 20%.* Fortify Shouts, 0.2 pts for 28800 secs
>
> **Blessing of Zenithar** *Prices are 10% better.* Fortify Barter, 10 pts for 28800 secs
>
> **The Gift of Charity** *+10 Speechcraft for 3600 seconds.* Fortify Persuasion, 10 pts for 3600 secs

Shamelessly copied from http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blessings

Comment: I can't help but suspect that the strength of the Blessing of Talos is a bug.  I imagine it was intended to be 20%, the same as the Amulet of Talos, but somebody put the decimal point in the wrong place. ;-)

Comment: @BenBlank I was thinking the same... but thats what the wiki said ;p

Comment: where can i find the little blessing stones :/

Comment: 0.2 pts IS the 20% Take any number, multiply it by 0.2--the result is 20% of the original number. So this is only a "bug" in the consistency of the game's descriptions and interface, not in the actual strength of the effect.

Comment: @kevin the shrines are mostly inside the temples within the towns.  You can find 8 of the 9 divines inside the solitude temple, but other towns mostly contain one or two.  Talos can be found in whiterun.

Comment: Also there is a Talos Shrine in Windhelm (in his temple), in Markath (again in the temple), and in Riften - in the SW ? corner near the graveyard.

Answer (score 3):

Equipping the Talos amulet and receiving the blessing will compound both into reducing shout time 40%. To prove this, choose a shout and look at its recharge time, and then either equip the amulet or receive the blessing by itself. You'll notice the recharge time has changed. Equip both and view it again to see it's been further reduced. Blessings of Talos upon you. Shout your foes into dust.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other answers, here are other blessings not yet mentioned:

#### Name — Description — Source

Note: These blessings will stack with each other and shrine blessings.

- **Blood of the Ancients (Dawnguard DLC)** – Your Vampiric Drain spell absorbs Magicka and Stamina from your victims for 9 days. – Drink from the [Bloodstone Chalice](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bloodstone_Chalice).
- **Dragonslayer's Blessing** – 10% increased Critical Hit Chance vs. Dragons for 5 days – [Esbern](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Esbern)
- **Tainted Blood of the Ancients** (Dawnguard DLC) – Your Vampiric Drain spell absorbs Magicka and Stamina from your victims for 1 day, but at the cost of 30 less health – Drink from the [Bloodspring](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Redwater_Spring).
- **The Gift of Charity** – +10 Speechcraft for 3600 seconds. – [Giving a coin to a beggar](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Quest_all_Beggars_Have) / Giving a gift to your [child](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Child#Adoption) (Hearthfire DLC)
- **Voice of the Sky** – Animals will neither attack nor flee from you for 24 hours. – Reading all ten etched tablets on the way leading to [High Hrothgar](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:High_Hrothgar).

#### Dragonborn DLC Blessings

- **Blessing of Azura** – Resist 10% of magic for 8 hours – [Temple, Raven Rock](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Temple)
- **Blessing of Boethiah** – One–handed weapons do 10% more damage for 8 hours – [Temple, Raven Rock](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Temple)
- **Blessing of Mephala** – Prices are 10% better for 8 hours – [Temple, Raven Rock](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Temple)
- **Blessing of the Stag Prince** – Receive an additional x Health and Stamina while Bow of the Stag Prince is equipped ([details here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Blessings)) – Obtained by equipping the [Glass Bow of the Stag Prince](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Glass_Bow_of_the_Stag_Prince)

Note: Even if you betrayed Azura during [The Black Star](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Black_Star), you will still be able to gain her blessing.

Source:

- [UESP Wiki, "Skyrim – Blessings" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blessings)
- [UESP Wiki, "Dragonborn – Blessings" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Blessings)